# Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be maximal in $R$. Show that $\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ is an $R/\mathfrak{m}$-vector space for all $n\geq 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $\mathfrak{m}$ a maximal ideal of $R$.  Show that $\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ is an $R/\mathfrak{m}$-vector space for all $n\geq 0$

I mostly just want to make sure I didn't miss something in my proof:

So since $\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ is a ring, the only property left to prove is that $\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ is closed under scalar multiplication.  I define scalar multiplication to be the product of elements in $R$ and then at the end I mod out by $\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$.

So an arbitrary element of $\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ looks like: $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^ta_k+\mathfrak{m}^{n+1},$$ where $a_k=c_k\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^nm_i$ for $c_k,m_i\in\mathfrak{m}$.

And an arbitrary element of $R/\mathfrak{m}$ looks like:
$$r+\mathfrak{m}.$$

Thus we take their product to obtain:

$$(r+\mathfrak{m})(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^ta_k+\mathfrak{m}^{n+1})=r\sum_{k=1}^ta_k+r\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}+\mathfrak{m}\sum_{k=1}^ta_k+\mathfrak{m}\cdot\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}.$$

The second term is clearly in $\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$.  The fourth is also since $\mathfrak{m}^{n+2}\subseteq\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$. And the third term as well since $\mathfrak{m}$ does not contain units.  Thus this sum becomes $r\sum_{k=1}^ta_k+\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$, which is what I wanted.  Is this good, am I done?  Thanks.

Comment: You are not done when you are not sure. When you really want to *understand* quotients, better forget about cosets and remember the homomorphism theorem. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335229

Comment: Dear pajamas, Do you know about modules over a ring?  This is a concept that makes this question much easier to work with (as in Martin Brandenburg's answer below).  Also, do you know the concept of ideal?  The scalar multiplication on $\mathfrak m^n/\mathfrak m^{n+1}$ is induced by the $R$-action on $\mathfrak m^n$ arising from its structure as an ideal.  Regards,

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I swore on the pajama name never again to use a homomorphism.

Comment: @pajamas: Good luck!

Comment: how do I check mark my question as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalize it to make the problem easier. If $R$ is a ring, $I$ is an ideal of $R$, and $M$ is an $R$-module, then the $R$-module $M/IM$ becomes an $R/I$-module. There are at least three possible ways to see this (increasing in abstraction):

- Just verify directly that $\overline{r} \cdot \overline{m} := \overline{rm}$ defines a module structure. In particular one has to prove that this is well-defined.
- $R \to \mathrm{End}(M) \to \mathrm{End}(M/IM)$ kills $I$, hence factors through the quotient $R/I$.
- $M/IM = M \otimes_R R/I$.

In your case $I=\mathfrak{m}$ and $M=\mathfrak{m}^n$. Here is another interesting example (as requested by  Math Gems): When $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ is a prime number, then for every abelian group $A$ we get the $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space $A/pA$.

Comment: This is a bit beyond my knowledge level, so I can revisit it once I have the requisite algebra, I'd still like to know if there were in any flaws in my reasoning above.

Comment: It is not beyond your level. I only use the notion of the quotient of a module by a submodule.

Comment: @Andreas: Is it a quote? Ok I already know http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40005/ ;)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I was quoting you, of course, à la social network.

Comment: It would be very helpful to give some other examples of the more general context. Probably you know some nice examples that are accessible to the OP.

Comment: Dear Martin, Regarding the "beyond my ... level" comment, it may be that the OP doesn't know modules yet.  Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ is an $R$-module, to show that it is also an $R/\mathfrak{m}$-module (i.e. a $R/\mathfrak{m}$-vector space), you must show that, as you said, scalar multiplication is well-defined. So if $\bar{a},\bar{b}$ are two elements of $R/\mathfrak{m}$, you need to show that $\bar{a} \cdot m = \bar{b} \cdot m$ in $\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$. This is equivalent to show that $(a-b) \cdot m = 0 \in \mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$.

This is equivalent to showing that multiplication by something in $\mathfrak{m}$ is zero in $\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$. But this is easy... (I leave it tou you to convine yourself of that...)